# Calling Node.Js Rest API(POST) from Java Spring MVC

Tags: java, node.js, spring, rest

How to integrate node.js and java micro services. I'm able to call node rest api from java spring mvc but not able to post data to node api. Getting empty body in request object at node project.

FYI: Node.js(express) -REST api(POST method)
     Spring MVC -REST -api(POST method)

Java:

```
String url = "localhost:3010/upload";
JSONObject jsonob1=new JSONObject(); jsonob1.put("upfile", file);
jsonob1.put("ty", "ACT"); 
HashMap<String, String> header = getHeaderValues(uploadreq.getAuthToken(), "action"); 
status = getHttpClient.executePostRequest(url,jsonob1,header); 
LOGGER.debug("result {}", status);
```

NodeJs:

```
var express = require("express"); 
var router = express.Router(); 
router.post('/upload', function (req, res) { console.log(req); });
```

Comment: Please post your code that is working and your code that is not.

Comment: String url = "http://localhost:3010/upload";
    JSONObject jsonob1=new JSONObject();
    jsonob1.put("upfile", file);
 jsonob1.put("ty", "ACT");
 HashMap<String, String> header = getHeaderValues(uploadreq.getAuthToken(), "action");
 status = getHttpClient.executePostRequest(url,jsonob1,header);
 LOGGER.debug("result {}", status);

Comment: NodeJs-
var express = require("express");
var router = express.Router();
router.post('/upload', function (req, res) {
 console.log(req);
});

Comment: Please remember you can edit your own question no matter what level of reputation you have. Please add missing info by editing question body next time.

Answer (score 0):

Please ignore it, its resolved by myself, Access req.body at nodejs side as following

```
var qs = require('querystring');if(req.method=='POST') {
     var body='';
     req.on('data', function (data) {
         body +=data;
     });
     req.on('end',function(){
         var POST =  qs.parse(body);
         console.log(POST);``
     });}
```